# Configuring C++11 in Netbeans

Tags: c++, c++11, netbeans-7

I am using Netbeans 7.2, and I have downloaded GCC 4.7 using the Cygwin setup.  I have also added the directories to my PATH and I believe configured the settings in NetBeans appropriately.  No matter what I do, I get the error: 
-std=c++11 not recognized.

This line, from source code that I need to use, is particularly causing problems:

```
using size_type = long unsigned int;
```

Is this specific to c++11 syntax?

Answer (score 27):

With GCC 4.7.2 it compiles if you use the -std=c++11

```
C:\Users\ferenc>type using_test.cpp
#include <iostream>

using size_type = long unsigned int;

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
        std::cout<<sizeof(size_type)<<std::endl;
        return 0;
}

C:\Users\ferenc>g++ -std=c++11 using_test.cpp

C:\Users\ferenc>a.exe
4

C:\Users\ferenc>
```

1. Make sure that you have pointed NetBeans to the correct MinGW version.
   To do that, go to `Project Properties` **>** `Build` **>** `Tool Collection` **>** `...` **>** `Tool Collection Manager` and
   there you can set the path to the proper g++ version.
2. Make sure that you have set the correct compiler options:

   `Project Properties` **>** `Build` **>** `C++ Compiler` **>**

   `Compilation Line` **>** `Additional Options`

   set it to: `-std=c++11`

Answer (score 5):

Simpler Steps:

1. Open the project
2. File menu > Project Properties
3. Under Build > C++ Compiler > C++ Standard > C++14/ C++11