# Priority queue using selfmade struct

Tags: c++

I've defined the following struct:

```
struct tussenData {
    int van;
    int naar;
    int gewicht;
    bool operator
    <(tussenData const& x, tussenData const& y) {
    return x.gewicht < y.gewicht;
}
};
```

Now I'd like to use this in a priority queue, I'm trying to achieve this as follows:

```
std::priority_queue<tussenData, std::vector<tussenData>,std::greater<tussenData>> pq;
```

However I'm getting the follow error:

```
Unable to resolve identifier priority_queue
```

My includes are as follows

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <stack>
#include <exception>
#include <queue>
#include <functional>
```

Comment: What compiler are you using and how are you compiling?

Comment: What is your compiler? Ensure that you use right predicate std::greater, for this predicate you have to define operator>.

Comment: works for me, if fix code like this `bool operator>(tussenData const& y) const`, you should specify your compiler and give full .cpp file that not compiled

Comment: I've not yet compiled, I'm using Netbeans IDE and the IDE triggers the Unresolved Identifier error.

Comment: What C++ compiler is Netbeans using?  You may be interested in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867428/configuring-c11-in-netbeans

Comment: Seems to be what I need, thanks!

Comment: Okay.  I am gong to close as a duplicate then.  If it doesn't work out you can update the question and ping me and I'll reopen it.