# configuring netbeans 8.0 for c++ 11 to write threading code

Tags: multithreading, c++11, netbeans-8

I installed net beans 8.0 since it supports  c++ 11 features. I want to write some multi threading code with in netbeans. but the #include  headers are not within this .. do i have to manually set up this. please guide

I tried with visual 2015 .. it was painfully slow and cumbersome to fix so many troubles related to operating system and vs 2015 itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuring C++11 in Netbeans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867428/configuring-c11-in-netbeans)

Comment: Thats not the solution. its just for c++ configuration. i want to code for multithreading